# Firebase Firestore: custom admin access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, admin, rules

In Firebase Firestore, I'm trying to allow only (custom-assigned) admins to write/update/delete resources, and for that I've got these security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /resources {
      allow read;
      allow write, update, delete: if get(/users/$(request.auth.uid).isAdmin);
    }
    match /resources/{resource} {
      allow read;
      allow write, update, delete: if get(/users/$(request.auth.uid).isAdmin);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm signing in with the user that is marked as an admin in the *users* collection:

[image: users collection has a single admin]

**NfwIQAjfNdS85yDvd5yPVDyMTUj2** is the UID gotten from the Authentication pane:

[image: The user exists]

However, for some reason (**UPDATE:** reasons identified; see answer), I'm getting *PERMISSION_DENIED* errors when writing to the *resources* collection after being absolutely sure I'm signed in with the admin user.

Perhaps it is possible to view request logs from Firestore? Then I could have a look at what `request.auth.uid` looks like to match it up with my collections and rules.

Comment: in `rosource` do we need to add field `isAdmin` or not?

Comment: You can use custom claims for role based access, if using cloud functions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While writing my question, I made it work! I made two mistakes, both of which could have been avoided if I read the docs properly.

**Firstly**, all calls to the [service-defined function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security#service_defined) `get` needs to prefix the path with */databases/$(database)/documents/*. So that this rule:

```
allow write: if get(/users/$(request.auth.uid)).isAdmin;
```

becomes this:

```
allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).isAdmin;
```

It's long, I know, but that's how it is. I'm not sure why Firestore isn't able to do that by itself, though, seeing as that same path prefix will stay the same across all calls to `get`, but perhaps this is for some future feature that isn't ready yet, like cross-database querying or something.

**Second**, the `get` function will return a [resource](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security#resource_1), which in turn you'll need to call `.data` on to get the actual data that it contains. Thus, instead of doing this:

```
get(/path/to/user/).isAdmin
```

you'll need to do this:

```
get(/path/to/user/).data.isAdmin
```

---

Now I just wish I was able to extract that logic into a [user-defined function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security#developer_defined):

```
function isAdmin() {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
}
```

But doing so results in a *PERMISSION_DENIED* again, and without knowing what's actually going on in the function, I'm not sure if I'll spend more time trying to figure this out now.

**UPDATE:** @Hareesh [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47155710/664955) that functions must be defined within the scope of a matcher, so it's possible to put the function in the default top-level matcher like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isAdmin() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin == true;
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone following this approach, be aware that if you provided write permission to users to write to their own user doc `/users/${userId}`, a savvy keen user could set a property `isAdmin`to True, and will be considered as admin. To prevent that, you will either create a security rule to deny write requests with `isAdmin` to user doc or keep that `isAdmin` property in a separate firestore document where users don't have write access to.

Comment: Indeed. You'll definitely not want users to be able to set themselves to admins. 

Comment: While this is good method and shown in firebase docs, but this need a read database for every time security rules evals . Custom claims is more suited for 'role-based' access, which simplifies security rules. See here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: I have a question, i am only using firebase and saving the notifications in firestore and accessing and using from the backend , how can i protect the firestore that only i can access it from backend and no body else can do it. 
i had done (read , write to true) also tried this (read,write true if user != null). 
Which one i can use.

Answer (score 4):

Some points i noticed

`match /resources` is pointing to a collection, that rules has no effect on its documents. here i am quoting from the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#rules_dont_cascade)

> Rules for collections don't apply to documents within that collection. It's unusual (and probably an error) to have a security rule that is written at the collection level instead of the document level.

so you don't have to write rules for collections

Then in the rules `allow write, update, delete:` you can say either `allow write:` or specifically `allow create, update, delete:` any of the three options or combine them.

try this

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /resources/{resource} {

        function isAdmin() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).isAdmin ||
            get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
        }

        allow read;
        allow create, update, delete: if isAdmin();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, great! I hadn't noticed the part about rules on the collection level. Thanks! Also, I actually had `create, update, delete` previously, then I've just experimented with different things in order to make it work, but you're right, that's supposed to be just `write`. Will try putting the function inside of the matchers, but that kind of defeats the purpose in my opinion. :-)

Comment: yes you only use functions for multiple validations like [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#writing_custom_functions)

Comment: So putting the function in the top-level matcher (/databases/{database}/documents) works fine! Then there's no problem, really. Thanks, @Hareesh, I'll update my answer. :-)