# How we set the header values as a authentication in cloud firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have applied the rule in firebase. having added one user in firestore auth and changed rule accordingly.My custom firestore rule is

```
match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write :if request.auth == 'Here user values will add';
```

From my nestjs code have been added the user as a header in controller class and pash this vales to service layer but when passing this values in our firebase service class this is my below code in firebase service class.

Below is my controller class

```
@Get('/list')
async getDocumentList(@Headers('user') user: string): Promise<any> {

 console.log("controller"+user);
    try {
        return await this.incidentService.getIncidentList(user);

    } catch (e) {
        throw new HttpException(e.message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

and firestore service class is :-

```
async getDocumentList(collectionName: string,user ): Promise<any> {

    console.log(user);
    
    const docSnapshot = await firestore().collection(collectionName).get();                    
                          
    const docList = [];

    docSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        docList.push(doc.data());
    });
    return docList;
}
```

I want to know How I will pass/notify or make condition the user values to firestore so that's make this user values as a admin and apply rule based on this values ?

what will be code in our firestore service class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information that is passed from your read request to the Firestore security rules is:

- The path (and or query) that is being requested.
- The current auth object from the client, including any information that's in its ID token.

You cannot pass other information along and expect that to show up in the security rules.

So if you want to mark specific users as application administrators and give them specific access in your security rules based on that, you will have to embed that information in one of the above items.

The typical approach is to either [add this information as a custom claim to the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), or to [store it in the database itself and look it up based on the UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154298/firebase-firestore-custom-admin-access).

Comment: This is my rule in cloud firestore

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
            allow read; 
              allow write:if (request.auth.token.admin) == false;
}}}

->And code I made change 

admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(environment.fireBaseAdminId, {admin: true}).then(() => {
}

but still able to write in DB.it seems rule is not working

Comment: Keep in mind that custom claims can take up to an hour to propagate from the server to your client (and from there to the security rules).

Comment: I come to know that "The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user accounts"  when I am applying the rule in cloud firestore ...Since I am initialized app from admin ...rule is not working even after apply one hours

Comment: Thanks for checking. This is getting hard to troubleshoot in comments, so I recommend opening a new question with the minimal repro. In this case that'd be: 1) the rules, 2) the document you expect to read, 3) the code of how you set the claim, 3) the client-side code that logs the claim and then makes the failing call to the database.