# Firebase rules passing in simulation but not on same operation in front-end

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore rule for a collection "orders" and i use the simulator tool to est my rules and they definitely pass for all reads, yet when i attempt to display the orders in my console i get an error

Rules

```
match /orders/{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if isAdmin();
      allow create: if isOrderOwner();
    }

function isAdmin() {
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.userinfo.isAdmin;
}

function isOrderOwner() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/orders/$(request.auth.uid)) == request.auth.uid
}
```

On my app, all i'm doing is console.log(orders) and i get this error:

```
Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

In my front end (react)

```
db.collectionGroup('orders').onSnapshot(snap => {
  let ordersArr = []  
  snap.forEach(doc => { 
    if(doc.data().orderid) 
      ordersArr.push(doc.data())
  })  
  setAllOrders(ordersArr)   
  console.log(ordersArr) // ->  this console causes the insufficient permissions error      
})
```

I can't figure it out, i very simply have allow read; for all documents in my orders collection.

Note: the orders are in a subcollection of the orders collection (i don' think that is the problem though)

Comment: well is it relevant? i just asking for the read -  and it has no function tied to it...

Comment: the query is to display the orders collection, that's all! when i console log my orders collection i get "the insufficient permissions" error

Comment: For completeness, did you redeploy your updated rules?

Comment: `setAllOrders` is a write operation to Firestore?

Comment: nop thats  just a react setState. the read operation is console.log(ordersArr) - that causes the permissions error. read my updated code please

Comment: S.Ramjit if you mean just publish yes. is that the same thing?

Comment: resetting my rules to allow all documents (like default rules) makes everything display correctly of course. SO the issue is not the front end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Firestore: custom admin access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154298/firebase-firestore-custom-admin-access)

Comment: The `console.log` isn't a read operation. It just displays the information in the console. If you remove it do you still get the error? Also yes I meant publish, apologies

Comment: Martin Zeitler nothing to do with my question...

Comment: Beside the question apparently being a duplicate, it is entirely unclear what functions `isAdmin()` and `isOrderOwner()` even do - which means, I could as well have close-voted for "missing debug information". Only because the code is being structured differently, this doesn't make a real difference... scroll up, the first question already asked for these functions, - which are unknown to us.

Comment: Can you try this path for collection group query? `/{path=**}/orders/{doc=**}`

Comment: Martin Zeitler sorry but cmpletely false. it is far from a duplicate. i saw that question it is completely different. also isAdmin and isOrderOwner have nothing to do with the read operation, so it is not relevant to this question. is it?

Comment: i appreciate you're help.
no it doesn't work firebase allows only one global wildcard for a match

Comment: @Uriel These functions need to be defined in the security rules - but the security rules you've presented do not feature them ...and so it it only normal to ask for them; isn' t it? The one answer I've linked just has the functionality in-lined, instead of encapsulated into a function (that's why I'd say there is not much difference).

Comment: ok ill add them. not that it makes a difference because im asking for read not write...

Comment: `/{path=**}/orders/{orderID}` ? If possible can you share any security rules above that? I'm just wondering if the match path is nested in another.

Comment: Martin Zeitler not really, because my problem is about reads not write...

Comment: Dharmaraj thats the only rule at the top. 
if i try this it has a syntax error: /{path=**}/orders/{'sgdsgryerfdh'} //sgdsgryerfdh = orderid

Comment: @Uriel Are you making these requests as a regular user or as an admin? Can you add in the shape of a regular user's data and an admin's data (`/users/someUserId`)? Also, how many order documents are there in your database?

Comment: There's no need of `' '` in the wildcard... don't hard code any string in there.

Comment: -as the admin
- there are 3 and they are subcollections

Comment: Dharmaraj ok well it didn't work
but i think i found the reason. all my other collections work for reads and rights except this one and the difference with this one (orders) is that all the data is in subcollections. Do i need explicit rules for a subcollection to allow reads and writes?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database structure once ?

Comment: Can you add the full document paths of the documents you are expecting to be matched by this query to your question? I'm not following what you mean by them being subcollections - do you mean that they are at `/orders/someUserId/orders/someOrderId`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `collectionGroup` so if I assume `orders` is a sub-collection for each document in parent collection, let's say users or customers, the rules should ideally be something like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /{path=**}/orders/{orderId} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false; // <- any rules you have for writes
  }
}
```

I ran the following query and the read operation was allowed:

```
const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("orders").get();
console.log(snapshot.size, "docs")
```

The `{path=**}` is a recursive wildcard as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups).

The documentation says,

> In your security rules, you must explicitly allow collection group
> queries by writing a rule for the collection group:
>
> 1. Make sure rules_version = '2'; is the first line of your ruleset. Collection group queries require the new recursive wildcard `{name=**}`
>    behavior of security rules version 2.
> 2. Write a rule for you collection group using match `/{path=**}/[COLLECTION_ID]/{doc}`.

Comment: Yes thank you finally an answer that considers the actual problem and that solves it! thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Because both `isAdmin()` and `isOrderOwner()` use a `get()` call, you are likely exceeding the limit for your query. You will need to apply a `limit()` to your collection group query and paginate through the results. As each rule uses two `get()` calls, you will only be able to retrieve up to 10 documents per query request.

Paraphrased from the [Cloud Firestore Security Rules Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits):

> A limit of 10 `exists()`, `get()`, and `getAfter()` calls applies to single-document requests and query requests.
>
> A limit of 20 `exists()`, `get()`, and `getAfter()` calls per request applies to multi-document reads, transactions, and batched writes.
>
> For example, imagine you create a batched write request with 3 write operations and that your security rules use 2 document access calls to validate each write. In this case, each write uses 2 of its 10 access calls and the batched write request uses 6 of its 20 access calls.
>
> **Exceeding either limit results in a permission denied error.**

Comment: helpful to know. bu i removed the isAdmin and isOrderOwner rules and left only alow read and i still get the permissions error.